# Single Sign On between ArcGIS Online and GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, arcgis-online, authentication

I'm trying to add WMS layers in ArcGIS Online without the need to sign in again to GeoServer. To achieve a Single Sign On, I have federated ArcGIS Online with our Okta IdP using Open IDC protocol. We made sure that the option "Send access token in header " is enabled while configuring the OIDC login. However, this [link](https://nam10.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.arcgis.com%2Fen%2Farcgis-online%2Freference%2Fogc.htm%23ESRI_SECTION1_136F31FA3EFC4B0A875D4E590CE59550&data=05%7C01%7Cahmed.shehata%40halliburton.com%7C59339978a61445863e5708dbf28f364c%7Cb7be76866f974db79081a23cf09a96b5%7C0%7C0%7C638370469133686982%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=Q9irnrey%2BMmD1u9SLpzeXhpNtI%2BrRtH4SfgvLWIGdRk%3D&reserved=0) says token-based OGC layers aren't supported in ArcGIS Online.

Is there anyway to achieve a SSO between ArcGIS Online and GeoServer?